Is there a way to pass down the object itself as props?
I have an object that has its component inside, and i'd like to fetch the object info inside that component:
const opciones = [ //todas las opciones de los compoentes
        {
            id: "TAB_inicio",
            texto: "Inicio",
            siguiente: "TAB_prueba",
            descripcionTitulo: "Bienvenido al programa de carga de Viajes",
            descripcion: "Selecciona lo que quieras hacer",
            icon: <FaCheckCircle />,
            next: next,
            contenido: <Inicio next={next} test={this} />,
            botonSiguiente: "Nuevo Viaje",
        },
        {
            id: "TAB_descripcion",
            texto: "Descripción",
            siguiente: "TAB_incluido",
            descripcionTitulo: "Descripcion",
            descripcion: "detalles importantes",
            prueba: function prueba() {
                console.log(this)
            },
            icon: <FaBookOpen />,
            next: next,
            contenido: <Descripcion  register={register} />,
            botonSiguiente: "Siguiente",
        },
    ]


I tried doing it by passing "this" but it doesn't work :D help please, i'm trying to understand some concepts with react.
I'm not sure how i would pass it here in the map:
 <section className='col-span-12 p-5 bg-gray-100 border-b-2 border-orange-400 rounded shadow-xl md:col-span-8 lg:col-span-10 dark:border-0 dark:bg-slate-800'>
            <DarkThemeSwitcher isDark={isDark} setDark={setDark} />
            {opciones.map((opcion) => (
                <div key={opcion.id} className={toggle === opcion.id ? "show-content" : "hide"}>
                    <div className='w-full pb-5 mb-4 text-left border-b-2 border-orange-400 dark:border-cyan-400'>
                        <h2 className='text-2xl font-semibold text-black dark:text-white'>
                            {opcion.descripcionTitulo}
                        </h2>
                        <span className='text-black dark:text-white'>
                            {opcion.descripcion}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {opcion.contenido}
                    </div>
                 
                </div>
            ))}

I have opcion.contenido to display the component but i want to pass some props which i can't do because it doesn't look like <Component ... /> it's just {opcion.contenido}

opciones.map((opcion) => <OpcionComponent opcion={opcion} key={opcion.id} />)...?

Also: React.cloneElement

Hello! hm i want the component to dynamically change, so if the obj is the second opcon it should grab the component that's inside it and i'd call it like this {opcion.contenido}. I'm not sure if it makes sense.

`
function actual(opcion_actual) {
    opciones.forEach((opcion) => {

        if (opcion.id === opcion_actual) {

            return opcion

        }
    });
}

`
i tried returning it but it gives undefined but when i console.log it does access it. I'm confused :' )
